# Date Subtraction Formula not returning correct answer

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I hope you can help. I have inherited an excel sheet with a formula that I don't fully understand.

Essentially I believe the formula is looking to determine the amount of time a task from creation date and time (Cell U2) took to complete from (Cell V2) both in hours and minutes.

This is taking into consideration that my teams working hours are 8:30 am until 17:00 pm Monday to Friday excluding weekends and Holidays noted as 25th December 2017

I have attached a picture for better understand

The issue is that formula in W2 is returning a 0

The formula that is returning a 0  In W2 is

```
=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(U2,V2,11,'Working Hours & Holidays'!$C$2)-1)*("17:00"-"8:30")+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(V2,V2,11,'Working Hours & Holidays'!$C$2),MEDIAN(MOD(U2,1),"8:30","17:00"),"17:00")-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(V2,V2,11,'Working Hours & Holidays'!$C$2)*MOD(U2,1),"8:30","17:00")
```

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

PIC 1

[image]

Comment: Answer might depend on what is in Working Hours & Holidays.

Answer (score 0):

This is a verion of a formula I've used often before and posted often, too - see [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/426101-calculate-only-working-hours-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends.html#post4208007)

Some of the U2 and V2 values are incorrect - try this version - changes marked in **bold**

=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(U2,V2,11,'Working Hours & Holidays'!$C$2)-1)*("17:00"-"8:30")+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(V2,V2,11,'Working Hours & Holidays'!$C$2),MEDIAN(MOD(**V2**,1),"8:30","17:00"),"17:00")-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(**U2**,**U2**,11,'Working Hours & Holidays'!$C$2)*MOD(U2,1),"8:30","17:00")

Comment: Hi Barry: Thank you for taking the time to respond it is greatly appreciated. Unfortunately the amended formula you gave me worked only in in the 2nd line of my pic example returning me 0:04 in cell W3 but cell W2 still remains at 0:00 have I done something wrong?

Comment: The formula is only counting working hours, defined as 0830 to 1700, example 1 doesn't contain any hours in that range, hence 0 is correct result, do you need the formula to work differently?